# T-SQL query assistance two single quotes in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to understand this t-sql query but I'm not sure what the 'where' clause means. Here is the query:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.ID1 = p.ID1,
    s.FIRST_NAME = p.FIRST_NAME,
    s.LAST_NAME  = p.LAST_NAME,
    s.DEPT_DESCR = p.DEPT_DESCR
FROM dbo.DIRECTORY_VW S
JOIN ps.STAGING_DIRECTORY_VW P ON s.ID = p.ID
WHERE p.ID <> ''
```

I understand the query updates ID1, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, and DEPT_DESCR values on the DIRECTORY_VW view with the values from the STAGING_DIRECTORY_VW, where the ID is the same, but what does the `<> ''` mean? `<>` is NOT EQUAL in T-SQL but I'm having trouble finding what two single quotes do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: two single quote is representing an empty string,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`''` in tsql is an empty string.  It's a string that is not NULL, but also has nothing in it.

So,

`someVal <> ''` is not the same as `someVal IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Two back-to-back apostrophes (`''`) is a common way of representing an empty string, so the `WHERE` clause is simply where `p.ID` is not equal to an empty string.